# Definir a altura inicial do textarea de acordo com seu conteúdo

Tags: css, angular

Utilizo um formulário angular reactivo que ao salvar deixa todos os campos desabilitados. Acontece que textarea cria um scroll e dificulta a leitura para quem apenas esta visualizando.

Ja tentei o seguinte com css:

```
textarea:disabled {
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: justify;
 resize: none;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ela expandisse conforme seu conteúdo, que se comportasse como uma DIV com seus devidos paddings.

Comment: A pergunta foi editada, favor considerar